# Chat owner's name not in italics

Tags: support, chat, room-owner

I recently noticed in [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) that the room owner, [@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/81339), doesn't have his name in italics, like most room owners do.  Is this a bug?

Comment: You sure it isn't just showing me as a mod? It used to be in italics prior to my becoming a mod.

Comment: That's quite possible.  Shouldn't it be in italics *as well*, though?

Comment: No. Pretty certain you can only have either blue **or** italics.

Comment: Too bad.  Not that it makes any difference, but it could be neat all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287335/152859) mentions correctly, the reason is the user is both moderator and room owner.

While I agree the expected behavior for a user who is both moderator and room owner is to have the name both blue and in italics, I'm not sure it's really needed.

Being a moderator "overrides" being room owner. Moderator has all the RO powers, and more. So, the fact a moderator also happens to be a room owner is minor and not really relevant.

That said, some people notice the font style before the color, so for them it might be confusing, they'll think the user is just a room owner.

All in all, while I agree it's most likely an overlook on the developer's side, I would be fine leaving it as it is.

Answer (score 5):

The owner in question, Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, is a moderator.

Moderators forego the - questionable - prestige of having their names in italics when they become a moderator. On the upside, they get blue names instead!

Comment: A blue name?? Really? *I feel special.* :o)